# User Class not found in Laravel 5

Tags: php, rest, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have got the following Problem.
I have just upgraded to Laravel 5 from 4.2 but my UserController which I first just copied to the new Controllers folder does not work.

It always tells me that it does not fiend the User Model.

My Code looked like the following when I copied it:

UserController.php

```
<?php

use App\Transformer\UserTransformer;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
public function index()
{
    App::abort(403, 'This is not allowed');
}

public function show($id)
{   
    $user = User::find($id);
    if($user->access_token!=Input::get('access_token')){
        return "It is not allowed to access data from other users";
    }else{
        $result = $this->respondWithItem($user, new UserTransformer);
        return $result;
    }
}

public function getID()
{   
    $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
    if($user->access_token!=Input::get('access_token')){
        return "It is not allowed to access data from other users";
    }else{
        $result = $user->id;
        return $result;
    }
}

public function register()
{
    $user = new User;
    $name = Input::get('name');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if($name != null AND $email != null AND $password != null){
        if(User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()){
            return "A user with this email already exists";
        }else{
            $user->name = $name;
            $user->email = $email;
            $user->password = $password;
            $user->save();
            return "Success";
        }
    }else{
        return "All fields are required";
    }
}

public function login(){
    $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
    if($user != null){
        if($user->password==Input::get('password')){
            $then =$user->time;
            $now = strtotime("now");
            $thenTimestamp = strtotime($then);
            $difference = $now - $thenTimestamp;
            if((empty($user->date) AND empty($user->time))OR($difference >=10800)OR($user->date!=date('d.m.Y'))){
                $user->access_token=self::getGUID();
                $timestamp = time();
                $user->date=date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
                $timestamp = strtotime("now");
                $user->time=date('H:i', $timestamp);
                $user->save();
            }
            return $user->access_token;
        }
        else
            return "Wrong username or password";
    }else
        return "Wrong username or password";
}

function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }else{
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*100000);
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);
        $uuid = 
            substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12);
        return $uuid;
    }
}

public function check(){
    $user = User::where('access_token', '=', Input::get('access_token'))->first();
    if($user != null){

    }else
    return "no session";
}
}
```

I did not have the the Controller namespaced and the User Model just worked out of the box. The UserTransformer does have the User Model included. Here the original copy:

```
<?php

use App\User;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
/**
 * Turn this item object into a generic array
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function transform(User $user)
{
    return [
        'id'             => (int) $user->id,
        'name'           => $user->name,
        'email'            => $user->email,
        'phone'         => $user->img,
        'mobile'       => $user->mobile,
        'address'       => $user->address,
    ];
}
}
```

That is everything that I needed to have the functions to work.

But now in Laravel 5 the UserController does tell me that the User class is not found. I have tried to add lines like this "use App/User" or "use App/Http/Controllers/User" to the UserController. It did not work.
I am not sure why since I have got my Transformer included I do not get any error for this but the User does not work.
I have also tried different use methods to include the User Model into the Transfomer since I though there might be an error but I do not get a working version.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you register and alias for User?

Comment: Plus, did you follow the upgrade steps from Laravel docs? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade

Comment: Where's your `User` class definition file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify just some things that could be interfering in loading the controller.

**The route**: by default, laravel comes with a provider called `RouteServiceProvider` found at `app\providers`. If you take a look to this file you will find that there is a variable named `$namespace`. This is very usefull if you want get more "clear" routes at `routes.php` file. For example, having `$namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'` you convert this...

```
Route::get('welcome', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@welcome');
```

to this...

```
Route::get('welcome', 'HomeController@welcome');
```

So yes, a short choice for write your rules. By default, the value of `$namespace` is set to `{Application Name}\Http\Controllers`

**The controller**: If you laravel installation is working with the `RouteServiceProvider` then your controller never will be found, because the routes prefix the namespace previously declared. So, which namespace should I use in controllers? there are two options:

1. Following the conventions of laravel 5 putting your controller at `app/Http/Controllers/` folder. Then, declare the namespace as default:

   ```
   namespace {Application Name}\Http\Controllers;
   ```

   and setting it at `routes.php` like:

   ```
   // weather is a controller
   Route::get('foo', 'UserController@index');

   // weather is a resource
   Route::resource('api-user', 'UserController');
   ```

   Notice that the namespace structure match the same folder structe where it is resides (Http/Controllers/)
2. Delete `RouteServiceProvider` from providers folder AND delete it from providers array in `config/app.php` file. Then, you can use "absolute" namespaces like:

   ```
   namespace {Application Name}\Http\Controllers;

   Route::get('foo', 'Myapp\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
   ```

**Application name and autoload**

did you question yourself why `app` folder is not added at namespace? Take a look the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "MyCoolApp\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

If you note, you will see that there is an alias that points out to `app/` folder. So, for app will response to the alias instead of `app\Http\Controllers`. 
I am no expert in this topic, hope somebody give me hand to expand this explanation, but I have read that `psr-4` is like a rule that make you match the namespace with the folder structure. As result, if your controller is like...

```
namespace MyCoolApp\Http\Classes;
```

The autoload class expects that your controller resides at a`app/Http/Classes/` instead of `MyCoolApp/Http/Controllers`

That is a reason why a controller could not be found.

Comment: I got it to work but now I have got a problem with a custom Model. I just added a new model file next to the User Model. The user model does work without any problem. But When I have included the new model and I want to use it it tells me when saying $token = new Token; It tells me class not found and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Ok fixed by myself. I did need to do composer dump-autoload