# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm a beginner at laravel and have been facing this error

Here's My Controller:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $user = User:: findOrFail($user);
      return view('confession')->with('user',$user);

    }
}
```

**Please Help And Thanks**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User Class not found in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420058/user-class-not-found-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing to include your model at the top `use App\User;`

Comment: For Laravel 8.x, add into UserController.php:

use App\Models\User;

Answer (score 4):

try this use `use App\User;`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $user = User:: findOrFail($user);
      return view('confession')->with('user',$user);

    }
}
```

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help to you Thank you..!!!  @Anonymous Chatbox

Answer (score 3):

You are using `User` model in your query but you have not included it in your controller.

In order to use it you must have to include it in your controller as below:

```
use App\User;
```

**OR**

to use it directly

```
$user =  \App\User::findOrFail($user);
```